# Linking to another post in blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

Suppose I have an older post in `contents/post/2019-04-29-old-post.Rmd` and I want to link to it from a new rmarkdown post.  Is there any way to do it without using the hardcoded url of the live site (so that I don't have to change all these cross links when the url of my site changes)?

Right now I do this:

```
In the [previous post](https://my.si.te/2019/04/29/old-post.html) we covered...
```

Is there a way to just identify the old post in some way (maybe the Rmd file name) and have blogdown/hugo generate the correct url?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have set your base URL correctly in `config.toml` like this:

```
baseurl = "https://my.si.te/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "A Hugo website"
theme = "hugo-lithium"
googleAnalytics = ""
```

and also have set the `[permalinks]` setting (also in `config.toml`):

```
[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"
```

Then the base URL becomes the root folder, so you can link like this:

```
In the [previous post](/2019/04/29/old-post/) we covered...
```

the generic form being

```
In the [previous post](/:year/:month/:day/:slug/) we covered...
```

Based on the `[permalinks]` option.

Comment: What if the file is stored just within the contents directory and not posts?